# Query: rsync - Copying Local folder to Remote Server from Remote Server

Tags: ssh, copy, rsync, remote-server

When I need to copy folder_01 from local_host to a remote_server I use the below syntax while executing the syntax at the local_host

```
user@user-localhost:~/local_directory/$rsync -avz --progress folder_01/ -e ssh user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/home/user/remote_directory/folder_01/
```

How does one copy folder_01 from local_host to a remote_server but this time executing the syntax at the remote_server?

This is because I am no longer allowed to login ssh directly to the remote_server (xxx.xxx.xx.xx) without login ssh to an intermediate remote_server (zzz.zzz.zz.zz) for security reasons.

Would like to experiment if I am able to pull the files from local_host to the remote_server after login to the remote_server. Googled, and the examples shared did not cover the above case.

Hope you can guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an rsync question, this is an ssh question.

Just add this to your `.ssh/config` file and all should work:

```
Host xxx.xxx.xx.xx
    ProxyCommand ssh zzz.zzz.zz.zz -W %h:%p
```

That just says, whenever I ask for x, tunnel through z to get there. You may need to fiddle with the user settings if your usernames don't match.